# Build failing, asking for Kotlin dependencies... kotlin not in use

Tags: codenameone

even though the app works just fine using the simulator... I'm unable to send my code to the compilation server.

If I use the upload button in Intellij, ant will say that compilation failed and that I need to see the log. If I try running the build manually I get a missing kotlin dependency error... but I'm not using Kotlin and this file is IDE generated.

I'm not sure how to tackle this problem

BUILD FAILED
J:\ClientePersonal\build.xml:10: The following error occurred while executing this line:
jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202018.3/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc/lib/kotlin-ant.jar!/org/jetbrains/kotlin/ant/antlib.xml:2: taskdef A class needed by class org.jetbrains.kotlin.ant.Kotlin2JvmTask cannot be found: kotlin/TypeCastException

Comment: I'll need the full error log (you can switch to text view in IntelliJ using the button on the top left). Which version of Java and IntelliJ are you using?